# how can i generate kendo chart similar to like this

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-chart, kendo-ui-mvc

I am trying to generate multi dimensional chart in kendo..

I have datatable like this
[image]

I am trying to generate similar to like this..

**Instead of Alphabets/Directions it should replace to "Year column 2010...2014..."**

**Instead of "ABC" It should come "Nationality --- Bahraini, Non Bahraini"**

**Instead of "DEF" It should come "Sector --- Public,Private, Other etc"**

**Instead of "New Column" It should come "Gender --- Male,Female"**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you figured how to make this chart but this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/lolokidepi/edit?html,js,output) have a similar example.

You only have to use [categoryAxis](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-categoryAxis) attribute.